# How do I enforce a constraint on a view that ensures 0 rows are returned in MSSQL

Tags: sql-server, view, constraints

Let me set the scene;

I have to talk to a system whereby there *will be* two types of users. Without going into details let's call them Super Users and Normal Users.

Super Users may or may not exist, but always reference a Normal User if they do exist. Normal Users always exist, but may be "soft" deleted.

There is an upgrade step that is happening on the system. All Normal Users that were Super Users get a new Super User account. Any Normal Users that are soft deleted *must not* have a Super User account, even if they had one before.

I have two tables, Message and ReceivedMessage.

Message contains a OnBehalfOfNormalUserId and the message content. ReceivedMessage contains the SuperUserId of the person that sent the message.

```
create table Message(MessageId int identity(1, 1) not null, OnBehalfOfNormalUserId int not null, Subject varchar(50) null, Content varchar(max) not null, constraint PK_MESSAGEID primary key (MessageId), contraint FK_ONBEHALFOFNORMALUSERID (OnBehalfOfNormalUserId) references User (UserId));
create table ReceivedMessage(QueueId int not null, MessageId int not null, SentBySuperUserId int null, constraint PK_QUEUEID primary key (QueueId), constraint FK_QUEUEID (QueueId) references MessageQueue (QueueId), constraint FK_SENTBYSUPERUSERID (SentBySuperUserId) references SuperUser (UserId));
```

*The tables contain more than this, but this should suffice for my example*

Now, a message could have been sent by the older system by someone who *was* a Super User, but who is now soft deleted and *cannot* be a Super User. This is achieved by placing "null" in the "SentBySuperUserId" column. However, unless the NormalUser has been soft deleted, this column *must* contain the SuperUserId. Any NormalUser account that is soft deleted *after* the migration will retain their SuperUser account but it won't be accessible. (I have no control over this process or what data is/isn't migrated)

The User table has a flag "IsDeleted". If this is marked, then SentBySuperUserId is allowed to be null, otherwise, it is not. (A SuperUser maps to a NormalUser via a bridge table)

I created a simple View that returns any NormalUserId where SuperUserId is null AND User.IsDeleted = 0. However, this won't suffice for an indexed view as a single message would be "ok" as far as a unique constraint is concerned. Given that I cannot sub-query, I cannot use CTE and I cannot use outer joins, I'm not sure how to enforce a constraint that ensures a view returns exactly 0 rows.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> How do I enforce a constraint on a view that ensures 0 rows are
>   returned in MSSQL?

You can't, the only type of constraint you can apply on a view is a unique constraint and it isn't possible to breach that with a single row.

However you can always just double up the result so that it does violate the constraint and you can enforce this declaratively.

You would need to create a table and insert two rows.

Add `CROSS JOIN dbo.TwoRows` to your view definition and create a unique index on it.

Now every row returned from your original query will be doubled up. And so if the original query returns any rows at all it will breach the unique index on it.

It would be nicer to be able to cross join onto a virtual table containing the two rows but derived tables etc are not permitted in indexed views.

---

NB: It did fleetingly occur to me that it might be possible to define the view so that it causes a runtime error if there is an attempt to materialise even a single row (e.g. divide by zero) but this is an even more horrible solution and also won't be guaranteed to work as the expression could be evaluated in a part of the plan before it was supposed to be filtered out.

Comment: Misread the first part of your comment. I may not have permission to do this, but I'll give it a try.

Comment: @Ehrys - The cross join is on a new table of two rows not the tables already participating in the query. The view will always actually contain zero rows as any rows at all will violate the constraint.

Comment: Yeah; I'd read that way of doing it on Google before coming here, but I wanted to avoid it if possible. I've asked the question to the DBA guys anyway, but the likelihood is that I won't be allowed to add a table with two rows in it that exists for no other reason than to duplicate my view output.

Comment: Marked yours as the answer. Unfortunately I'm being told I cannot utilise the two row table approach so I'll have to go back and re-design. Thanks for your help :)